# how to display and save mobile numbers in series from textview to Contact List

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am making an android app which will accept the first four digits from user and not only will display the numbers serial-wise starting from 1-100 but also will save them in the Contacts individually. For e.g. user types 9179 and the `TextView` will display from 9179000000 to 9179000100.
The problem is my code is saving the numbers in a single contact not as individual number. Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    test=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    getit=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            StringBuilder t = new StringBuilder(); 
            String result=getit.getText().toString();
            for (int l=series; l<=100; l++) {
                t.append(result);
                t.append(String.format("%06d", l)+"\n");
                }
            test.setText(t.toString());  
            String sphone=test.getText().toString();

        /*  String result=getit.getText().toString();
            test.setText(result);  */

            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
            int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                    .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());

            ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                    .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValueBackReference(
                            ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID,   rawContactInsertIndex)
                    .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, sphone) // Number of the person
                    .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build()); // Type of mobile number                    
            try
            {
                ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            }
            catch (RemoteException e)
            { 
                // error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (OperationApplicationException e) 
            {
                // error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't check your `ContentProviderOperation` code but if it is right and working, the rest of the code should be something like below.

You are creating only 1 `String sphone` after the for loop. Instead, you the for loop should extend to the creation of `ContentProviderOperation` objects. With this and `applyBatch` function, you can add multiple contacts at once.

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final String result = getit.getText().toString();
            ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();

            for (int l=series; l<=100; l++) {
                String sphone = result + String.format("%06d", l);

                int rawContactInsertIndex = ops.size();

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, null)
                        .withValue(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, null).build());

                ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
                        .newInsert(Data.CONTENT_URI)
                        .withValueBackReference(
                                ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactInsertIndex)
                        .withValue(Data.MIMETYPE, Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
                        .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, sphone) // Number of the person
                        .withValue(Phone.TYPE, Phone.TYPE_MOBILE).build()); // Type of mobile number

            }
            try {
                ContentProviderResult[] res = getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
            } catch (OperationApplicationException e) {
            }
        }
```

Comment: By the way, is there a way to get the values of 'l' for "for" loop from edittext? Like: 
`edittext min, max;
//where min=9179000000 and max=9179000100 obtained from user.
for(l=min; l<=max;l++)

Comment: Just like you are getting `9179` from the EditText, you can also get min and max values. You will get a String from the min and max EditTexts, then you just have to call `Integer.parseInt()` function to convert them to integers.

Comment: Ya but how to pass those integer values to another String for saving the numbers. This code shows error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "9179000000"

`String smin=min.getText().toString();
    String smax=max.getText().toString();
    
    test.setText(t.toString()); 
    int minvalue = Integer.parseInt(smin);
    int maxvalue = Integer.parseInt(smax);
    
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> ops = new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
    for (int l=minvalue; l<=maxvalue; l++) {
     
     String sphone = String.valueOf(l); `

Comment: I think it may be because it is too long. You can use long instead of int. And similarly Long.parseLong